# How do you replace multiple lines of text in path?

Tags: intellij-idea

With single line it's plain simple. But I could not find a way of replacing a block of text, not with structural replace, nor with replace in path of course. And replacing multiple times, just line by line isn't an option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

"Replace in Path" has an option to use regex.

To replace a block of text you can describe the block as a regex, using \n or \r\n for the line breaks (depending on your line-ending \n for LF and \r for CR).

If you are not familiar with regex yet, you can use a handy feature of IntelliJ:

1. You have to have the block of text in an open editor window of
   IntelliJ.
2. Select your block of text in the editor
3. Open "Replace in Path" (<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)

=> If the block of text is multiline IntelliJ will automagically check the regex option and put a fully escaped (including line breaks) version of your selected text in the search dialog. All you have to do now is enter the replace text and start the search.

BTW: "Structural Replace" does allow to replace multiline blocks of text/code. But plain text (without any variables) is not accepted as a valid search pattern.

Answer (score 21):

This seems to work at least in the latest version of `IntelliJ` (`2016.1.3`)

If you select multiple lines, click `CTRL+F`, then `CTRL+R`, you are able to replace multiple lines. A strangely now hidden feature of `IntelliJ`

On a mac that is ⌘+F, then ⌘+R

[image]

EDIT: As an alternative I've been using another feature with great utility for repeated multi line replace in a single file.

- Simply select the duplicate text you wish to replace
- press `control+G` repeatedly to highlight all areas.
- Then start typing. Your typing will replicate to all selected areas. All key movements are duplicated, avoid mouse clicks as it will cancel.
- Then press `esc` to stop. It should have replaced all occurances

Comment: doesn't work, don't know why.. *linux* (ctrl+F,ctrl+H is my shortcut)

Comment: you might be on  a different keymap, I guess it might be netbeans keymap

Comment: Doesn't work on my 2016.3.1 either, is it a mac feature?

Comment: It works (at least in Windows and Linux for me) - but not in the way the question was meant. With this you can only search and replace within one file. The question however was to replace "in path" which means "in all files in the same path (and subdirectories if selected)".

Comment: @Picl Good point, yes this is true, its only for a single current file

Comment: Works perfectly in Android Studio 3.2.1, which is based on some version of IntellIJ Idea 2018 (selected text is converted into newline character`\n`, but it still works and it's much better than writing this by yourself)

Comment: This seems to work sometimes for me on Windows, maybe something to do with line endings on the particular file I am in?

Comment: Works perfectly in Webstorm 2021.1 on Windows.